# ACAccount.h sudden error

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocoa

I was working on my project just fine and all of the sudden I get the following error in my project.

This is a problem in a in the `Accounts Framework`, which I didn't even get close to touch (or any framework). Specially since those files are locked.

Does anyone know why I am getting this and how to fix it?

Sorry I cant be more descriptive, but it suddenly happened and I never touched that.

[image]

Comment: What deployment target are you using? Also, if you highlight the VERY FIRST error, what's the code that it navigates to (and the few lines above it)?

Answer (score 0):

I got following error after editing ACAccount.h.

[image]

Open headers folder, select ACAccount.h and press ⌘z(undo).

[image]

or compare your ACAccount.h file with below code

```
//
//  ACAccount.h
//  Accounts
//
//  Copyright (c) 2011-2012 Apple Inc. All rights reserved.
//

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <Accounts/AccountsDefines.h>
@class ACAccountType, ACAccountCredential;

// The ACAccount class represents an account stored on the system.
// Accounts are created not bound to any store. Once an account is saved it belongs
// to the store it was saved into.

ACCOUNTS_CLASS_AVAILABLE(10_8, 5_0)
@interface ACAccount : NSObject

// Creates a new account object with a specified account type.
- (id)initWithAccountType:(ACAccountType *)type;

// This identifier can be used to look up the account using [ACAccountStore accountWithIdentifier:].
@property (readonly, weak, NS_NONATOMIC_IOSONLY) NSString      *identifier;

// Accounts are stored with a particular account type. All available accounts of a particular type 
// can be looked up using [ACAccountStore accountsWithAccountType:]. When creating new accounts
// this property is required.
@property (strong, NS_NONATOMIC_IOSONLY)   ACAccountType       *accountType;

// A human readable description of the account.
// This property is only available to applications that have been granted access to the account by the user.
@property (copy, NS_NONATOMIC_IOSONLY)     NSString            *accountDescription;

// The username for the account. This property can be set and saved during account creation. The username is
// only available to applications that have been granted access to the account by the user.
@property (copy, NS_NONATOMIC_IOSONLY)     NSString            *username;

// The credential for the account. This property can be set and saved during account creation. It is 
// inaccessible once the account has been saved.
@property (strong, NS_NONATOMIC_IOSONLY)   ACAccountCredential *credential;

@end
```

Comment: I havent modified the file and it looks exactly as the one you show :/. the error seems to be in one of my classes. tried restoring for back up... and restore files one by one (what a pain!) but the error doesnt show up... and then I do nothing and shows up again..... its so bizzar

Answer (score 0):

Did you import ACAccount.h directly? If so, don't do that. Import only top-level headers—in this case, that'd be `<Accounts/Accounts.h>`.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it wasnt that I modified AcAccount.h, which is difficult since Xcode alerts that you don't own that file, the problem was that I accidentally modified 'main.c', instead of giving an error on the line I accidentally modified it gave that misleading message.